# How to display top 5 user list in Django?

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. In this system, users do some analysis. I keep the information of these analyzes in a model named "ApprocalProcess". How can I display the top 5 users who made the most analysis in "ApprovalProcess"?

**models.py**

```
class ApprovalProcess(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='starter')
    doc_id = models.ForeignKey(Pdf, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    ...
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def approval_context_processor(request):
   approval_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.filter(user_id__company=current_user.company) 
   context = {
          'approval_list ': approval_list,
           .... 
    }
    return context
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Count
approval_list = ApprovalProcess.objects.values('user_id').annotate(Count('user_id')).order_by('-user_id__count')[:5]
```

First we find `user_id` duplicate in table and count it. Then we order descending with `-` in `-user_id__count` and get 5 users duplicatest in table.
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I added .values('user_id', 'user_id__image') but it takes path not image I tried {{list.user_id__image.url}} but it did not work. How can I fix it?